# How to delete a business network on local hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm using hyperledger composer with local instalation. Im testing differents networks deploying them several times so I need to remove old ones.
There is a composer command:

```
composer network undeploy
```

but is use to disable a business network, but a I need to completely remove it and free the namespace.

I suppopose there is no Composer command to do that, but maybe there is a way to do with the Fabric containers

Comment: Whats the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

See answer here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.network.undeploy.html . The namespace is in use but if you're using something like Docker and a Dev environment, you can always do a teardown with a YAML file and re-use.

Comment: 'undeploy' is no longer a valid subcommand on `composer network` fyi

Comment: So what to do in composer v.0.20.8??

Comment: see https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/composer/message/163 - suggest to move to Fabric new programming model https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/developing_applications.html and get the free developer extension which helps makes the devOps life easy for the app developer  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBMBlockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform